# Passing echos and string(s) simultaniously from PHP function to a document?

Tags: php

I have a function similar to this. That function mysqls and prints news. Now, depending on mysql result(s), this function may print something or not..

```
function print_div_boxes($mysql)
{
echo 'Print (large sum of) data & divs....';

$printed_already = 1;
}
```

PHP I wish to achieve

```
<?

print_div_boxes($mysql);

if(!$printed_already)
{
print_div_boxes($another_mysql);
}
?>
```

I simply want to pass `$print_already` to a document from that function, grab it as `global` or something.. any suggestions? Possible?

Comment: I could not understand what do you, exactly, want?!

Comment: @SEMSEM I want to grab $printed_already string from a function to a document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your question edit, you don't need return at all and some clear modification to your code as follows:

```
<?php
$printed_already = false;
function print_div_boxes()
{
global $printed_already;
echo 'Print (large sum of) data & divs....';

$printed_already = true;
}
?>

<?php
if(!$printed_already)
{
echo '<div>'; print_div_boxes(); echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thx SEMSEM that does it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely simply, all you need is:

Make sure that some variable (usually a boolean) indicates the result of the execution some function. This is very general approach.

So, in procedural code, it would look like this:

```
<?php

//initial state;
$already_printed = false;


/**
 * instead of using a global keyword, use reference
 * it makes code a bit "clean" 
 */
function print_div_boxes(&$already_printed) //<-- we are passing a reference, not a copy
{
  echo 'Print (large sum of) data & divs....';

  //A couple of thing to note:

  //1) Function Return value SHOULD NOT BE RESULT OF ASSIGNMENT!!!
  //2) No 'return' keyword actually required here, its VOID
  //3) You expect a logic, so use boolean instead of int. It's more appropriate

   $already_printed = true; 
}


//Then use it like:

if ( $already_printed === false ){

   print_div_boxes(&$already_printed);

}
```

Comment: Thx for this metal fan.. I'll keep this that in mind as I programm this.